# How to properly store Git files for multiple IDEs?

Tags: git, github, ide

I use multiple IDEs in different PCs, these are VS13/15/17, Eclipse, Netbeans, and they all create project files for a new one.

If I didn't like to create new project on a new PC for one code, could I keep all the project files on one repository? If so, how do I organise them to prevent misunderstandings in working tree?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure I got the question well, your IDEs create files (e.g. `.idea` file, or `.sln` file) in your project and it creates issues if you, for example, clone your project on another PC?

I think IDE files are developer specific and not project specific. Therefore I prefer adding them in a `.gitignore` file. So that if I use another editor, and it creates some files it needs, it does not affect the repository.

If you don't want to have to think about it every time, you can have a global `.gitignore`:

```
git config --global core.excludesfile ~/.gitignore-global
```

Here, the path `~/.gitignore-global` is just an example, you can choose another name.

And in it you add the IDE files you want to ignore. So all in your projects, they will be ignored by Git and will stay local to your environment.

I hope it will help.

Comment: "...IDE files are developer specific and not project specific..."  That's at best half true.  None of the IDE's would agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with storing IDE project files in source control.

First, the IDE files tend to be a mix of project data and user-specific data, and you'd need to commit only the former while omitting the latter.  This is easily done for some IDE's but not for others, and in any case the knowledge of how is IDE-specific.

Second, if multiple IDE's are used for the same project (by different users, or on different machines), then you end up with two sets of project files that can easily fall out of sync.  (I'm not talking about the case where everyone always uses VS for *this* part of the code, and everyone always uses Idea for *that* part of the code; I mean if Alice uses Idea for and Bob uses Eclipse for *the same part of the code*.)

As I understand your question, it seems like you have the latter problem.  In that case, you should see if you can find an IDE-neutral tool that can manage the project description, from which the individual IDE's can import it.  Then you can source-control just the IDE-neutral project description.  If that's not possible, then you may need to look into whether you can standardize on one IDE per module, at least to the extent of "this is the one managing the canonical project description, so if you want to use something else, you're on your own to import/export that info to your IDE as your IDE files won't be source controlled".

Even if each project is managed in one and only one IDE, there may still be benefits to using a project definition that isn't tied to the IDE where possible, but in that case you at least have the option of consulting your IDE docs to see what should, and what should not, be put in source control.

Comment: My workaround is create subdirs for specific IDE to store project files within ones. At least it works for Eclipse now, I only had to import source files as symlinks with relative path to the source dir.
The following question might be pretty noob, but it is okay to push build files, including program binary and make (cmake) files? Do they contain sensitive information?